# Need help on Checking the Signature of the Request from Amazon Alexa using Perl

Tags: perl, openssl

I am currently building a web service that should handle Alexa voice intents. The HTTP request I get from Alexa must be verified by checking a signature, as described [in the documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-a-web-service.html).

I am writing this code in Perl.

Amazon provides me with a `SignatureCertChainUrl` (which contains the certificate) and a signature, such as the following:

```
signature: KUm7g9saS4la2pwCPJHuk0ZOtNAPKnqE8qprp58rz1x9Em1DDp2mNdL56iiC7weGw3hzaN6lCmqjWL3zxtAC7HXmbDPdpYE5ZQJzVDCorAvAgb0VQTVMiRi2xcoNm+6KcQZe2/aFJgAxaDaJ3qID9EVPmhJMlHhFxD+/4Ip5O860Pk9GPTq1lC7gKGw5VmUinXZk/RCUnevnhL4TGfZYgEs4bI5QgHtdzlQdy+P6cfRqpuQrLEeFjHF13OA1uf/W5MjgF9dKjV0cCM3fAcBbz8O9itZbt1pC7LIJsDLYxQMcW7af98GdTv2dlnx3kb9JPERsTSni+rDKoukxgxQGcA==


-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I use the following code to decode and extract the public key as I have the first part of the certificate in a variable called $primary_cert .

```
my $decoded_cert2 = Crypt::OpenSSL::X509->new_from_string( $primary_cert );
my $pub_key = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_public_key($decoded_cert2->pubkey());
```

However I seem to be stuck on these steps:

6. Use the public key extracted from the signing certificate to decrypt the encrypted signature to produce the asserted hash value.
7. Generate a SHA-1 hash value from the full HTTPS request body to produce the derived hash value
8. Compare the asserted hash value and derived hash values to ensure that they match.

How should the Perl code perform those last steps?  I am using the following perl modules:

```
use CGI qw(:all);
use JSON qw( decode_json );
use Switch;
use Crypt::X509;
use MIME::Base64 qw(decode_base64);
use Crypt::OpenSSL::X509;
use Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA;
use Crypt::OpenSSL::VerifyX509;
use Try::Tiny;
```

Comment: Have you checked out this module? [Net::Amazon::AlexaValidator](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Amazon::AlexaValidator).

Comment: Yes, I did. But it does not work 100% as I get the same results. I don't quite understand what they are doing here.

   my $valid;
  try {
    $valid = $pub_key->verify($raw_request, $signature);
  } catch {
    return { success => 0, error_msg => "Amazon Alexa certificate failed public key validation: $_" };
  };

Comment: Regarding `try` and `catch`, read this article: [Perl try { } catch(e) { }](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1118605) or browse a bit... Perl does not have those, but there are libraries that add them for you like `Try::Tiny` or `TryCatch`.

Comment: I used the following code to extract the public key,
my $decoded_cert2 = Crypt::OpenSSL::X509->new_from_string( $primary_cert );
my $pub_key = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_public_key($decoded_cert2->pubkey());

But now how do I use that Public Key to decrypt the encrypted signature to produce the asserted hash value?

Comment: This is a java version of how alex skill kit does it https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-java/blob/master/src/com/amazon/speech/speechlet/authentication/SpeechletRequestSignatureVerifier.java